# Using Angular 2, VS2015, and IIS, how can I get my html template changes to reflect in a browser refresh?

Tags: node.js, angular, iis, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am developing an Angular 2 app using Visual Studio 2015.  My angular components reference html templates via the templateUrl property in the component decorator.  Since I have to eventually deploy to a virtual directory on IIS, I am developing using IIS instead of IIS Express.  Sadly, this constraint seems to preclude me from simplying borrowing the "npm start" capabilities for development which implement watch functionality that syncs my html templates to the browser quite nicely.  Instead, I have to use the tsconfig.json "compileOnSave" which does a great job of compiling the ts files into js files.  However, when I change an html template, there seems to be some caching and the changes are not reflected in a browser refresh.  How can I get my html template changes to reflect in a browser refresh after saving my changes in Visual Studio?

Comment: Probably you need Browser Sync https://github.com/peterblazejewicz/visual-studio-web-developer/blob/master/using-browsersync-as-a-tool-in-visual-studio.md

Comment: Great suggestion @PankajKapare.  I tried the following command line arguments: "/C browser-sync start --files "app/**/*.html" --proxy localhost --logLevel debug".  I started browser-sync from the tools menu after adding it via External Tools.  But, it doesn't seem to work right.  Hard to describe.  I'm getting all kinds of javascript errors which don't make sense, whereas I had no errors before.

Comment: I worked around the problem today. I created a default.htm (for deployment to IIS server) and an index.html page (for development). The default.htm has <base href="/virtualDirectoryName/" />. The index.html page has <base href="/" />. In development, I set startpage to index.html. In production, I set IIS default document to default.htm. This allows me to develop the site in the environment expected by "npm start" and to deploy into a virtual directory scenario.

I still can't help but think that there is a better solution out there.